# Adding button to move map Direction in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw, esri-leaflet

[image]

I want direction button in my Leaflet map so user can move map in mobile or desktop browser easily.

I am new and do not know how to start. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start here: [Leaflet.Pancontrol](http://kartena.github.io/Leaflet.Pancontrol/). Check the [code repository](https://github.com/kartena/Leaflet.Pancontrol) and download code to your `plugins` folder inside `leaflet` folder. Then in code just reference to the js file/files.